# Grunt-angular-templates - Don't compile html templates into single JS File

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular

I've created a basic angular project using yeoman's angular generator. While the standard Grunt process is fine in general, I do have my concerns with the way how the views get all minified into the same JS File.

If I have about 10 views on my Page, the requested view can't be seen until 'all' pages have been loaded, since their all in the same file.
I now want to modify the Grunt process, so that each HTMLviewfile get minified into its own file in a views directory. The main angular router should now request the view files as they are requested by the client (user).

Is there any way you could help me. All my research has resulted that the module 'grunt-angular-templates' is responsible for minification of all HTML views. I've yet to find out, how to keep the files from getting merged into a single file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, that in order to not minify all the view files into the script.js file, you have to remove the ngtemplate process from you gunt build task